# Maven/junit project organization

Tags: java, maven, junit

I have three packages:

- Foo provides a certain API
- FooMySQL (depends on Foo) implements the Foo API using MySQL
- FooPostgreSQL (depends on Foo) implements the Foo API using PostgreSQL

I have a bunch of junit tests, which should be run twice: once again FooMySQL, and once again FooPostgreSQL. They are the same tests, because the API should behave identically for both implementations, with only the setup and teardown slightly different.

Question: where should I define those tests? The most logical place appears to be in Foo. However, in Foo, they are not executable because Foo doesn't know of any implementation. I can put them into FooMySQL, but it appears I would have to have a full copy on FooPostgreSQL, as any "test" code defined in Foo cannot be referred to via the maven dependency mechanism from FooMySQL etc. (Is that correct, or perhaps I'm missing a trick?)

Alternatively I could create a separate FooTests project, which the FooMySQL and FooPostgreSQL tests could depend on. But that somehow sounds wrong, too. Is there a better idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just came across this: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-attached-tests.html

```
<dependencies>
 <dependency>
 ...
  <type>test-jar</type>
  <scope>test</scope>
 </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

This may solve my problem more elegantly; investigating.

Update: it works is it should!

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you should know is that what you should unit-test are your implementations. Always. I think you're leaning to that but I wasn't sure since you mentioned about testing `Foo`, I just want to make sure it's established.

So let's just do that without doing all the tests twice.

```
public abstract class FooTestBase {
  protected abstract Foo getFoo();
  @Test public void testBarMethod() {
    // Do some tests calling getFoo().
  }
}

public class FooMysqlTest extends FooTestBase {
  @Before public void setUp() {
    // Do stuff
  }
  @After public void tearDown() {
    // Do stuff
  }
  @Override protected Foo getFoo() {
    return new FooMysql();
  }
}

public class FooPostgresqlTest extends FooTestBase {
  @Before public void setUp() {
    // Do stuff
  }
  @After public void tearDown() {
    // Do stuff
  }
  @Override protected Foo getFoo() {
    return new FooPostgresql();
  }
}
```

Since you use Maven, by default `FooTestBase` will not be considered as a test class because it doesn't start with `Test` or ends with `Test` or `TestCase`. Therefore your tests will be centralized in `FooTestBase` and they will be executed in each child class.

Your tests will be written only once, and your setup/teardown will be specific to each implementation.

Comment: I know that much ;-) My question was: where does FooTestBase live? In src/test/java of Foo, of FooMySQL, of FooPostgreSQL, or in some other project? If in Foo, how do I set up the test dependency of the subclasses to it, because the Foo package does not/should not contain the test classes?

Comment: Ok, that wasn't clear: I had no idea why you mentioned Maven, tbh. Put it under `src/main/java` of FooTest project (yes, a 4th one) and mark this project as a **test** dependency of FooMysql and FooPostgresql.

Comment: I was a afraid that that was the best I could do :-( It destroys the whole idea of tests being part of the same project, though: if I have to have a separate "test" project from time to time, such as in my case, I might as well have the test sources in a separate project all the time; much easier to understand.